# Error al insertar en Mysql. There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first

Tags: c#, mysql

Lo que quiero es hacer un simple `INSERT` en C#, pero me sale actualmente este error:

> There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection
>   which must be closed first.

Código que va a insertar:

```
string QueryCon = "SELECT Id_Categoria FROM Categoria where Nombre='" + Categoria + "'";
connection.Close();
connection.Open();
MySqlCommand ConnCombo = new MySqlCommand(QueryCon, connection);
MySqlDataReader reader = ConnCombo.ExecuteReader();
while (reader.Read())
{
    Id_C = int.Parse(reader.GetString("Id_Categoria"));
}

string query = "INSERT INTO compra (Articulo, Categoria,Importancia,Obligatorio,Costo,Descripcion,Adquirir) VALUES('" + Articulo + "', '" + Id_C + "'," + Importancia + ",'no'," + Costo + ",'" + Descripcion + "','No','" + Mes + "')";

if (aprobar==true) {
    //create command and assign the query and connection from the constructor
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
    //Execute command
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); ------- Error
    connection.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El error sucede porque no cerrastes el `reader` antes de ejecutar tu `insert`. Para evitar este tipo de problemas, es muy importante de tomar la costumbre de usar bloques `using` para este tipo de objetos que implementan la interfaz `IDisposable`:

```
using(MySqlCommand ConnCombo = new MySqlCommand(QueryCon, connection))
{
    using(MySqlDataReader reader = ConnCombo.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            Id_C = int.Parse(reader.GetString("Id_Categoria"));
        }
    }
}

string query = "INSERT INTO compra (Articulo, Categoria,Importancia,Obligatorio,Costo,Descripcion,Adquirir) VALUES('" + Articulo + "', '" + Id_C + "'," + Importancia + ",'no'," + Costo + ",'" + Descripcion + "','No','" + Mes + "')";

if (aprobar==true) {
    //create command and assign the query and connection from the constructor
    using(MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection))
    {
        //Execute command
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Simplemente ejecutar `.Close()` no es suficiente, porque todavía cabe la posibilidad de que quede un data reader abierto si se lanza una excepción.  Usando el bloque `using`, tienes garantías que el recurso quedará cerrado al salir del bloque.

Adicionalmente, en el código corregido, de forma intencional evité incluir el código que tienes que maneja la conexión, porque no estoy de acuerdo con ello. No sé porque en general existe un enamoramiento con las conexiones globales, pero eso es sumamente peligroso y también puede llegar a causar el error que recibes y otras más si llegas a pasar a un ambiente multi hilos.  Es mejor que obtengas una instancia de conexión separada cada vez que necesites comunicar con la base de datos, y cerrarla inmediatamente después. Usualmente, los proveedores ADO.NET se encargan de trabajar con un pool de conexiones sin que te des cuenta de modo que en realidad no estás abriendo y cerrando conexiones de verdad a cada vez y el rendimiento es bueno.

De modo que el código, en realidad debería parecerse a esto, si quieres evitar problemas:

```
using(MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    connection.Open();

    string QueryCon = "SELECT Id_Categoria FROM Categoria where Nombre='" + Categoria + "'";

    using(MySqlCommand ConnCombo = new MySqlCommand(QueryCon, connection))
    {
        using(MySqlDataReader reader = ConnCombo.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                Id_C = int.Parse(reader.GetString("Id_Categoria"));
            }
        }
    }

    string query = "INSERT INTO compra (Articulo, Categoria,Importancia,Obligatorio,Costo,Descripcion,Adquirir) VALUES('" + Articulo + "', '" + Id_C + "'," + Importancia + ",'no'," + Costo + ",'" + Descripcion + "','No','" + Mes + "')";

    if (aprobar==true) {
        //create command and assign the query and connection from the constructor
        using(MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection))
        {
            //Execute command
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

Y finalmente, una nota adicional, porque no me di cuenta antes: es muy importante usar parámetros al construir tus consultas. Nunca concatenes los valores directamente en tu SQL. Aparte de problemas de seguridad de inyección SQL, que puedo entender que no te importe tanto según el tipo de proyecto que usas, también te evita problemas con comillas no escapadas correctamente, ayuda al servidor a mejorar el rendimiento, y mucho más. Es muy importante desarollar esa buena costumbre.

Answer (score 4):

La respuesta a tu pregunta, esta en el mismo error que envías. Dice que no como ya tienes un reader abierto no podes hacer otra cosa hasta cerrarlo. Si quisieras procesar en paralelo deberías abrir otra conexión.

Si no, basta con hacer `reader.Close()` una vez q terminaste de usarlo para que funcione.